# Selenium отказывается работать с proxy

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

Пытаюсь заставить selenium работать с proxy, но ничего не выходит. Вот код:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


proxy = "93.126.86.77:41890"
options = {
    'proxy': {
        'https': f'https://{proxy}',
    }
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), seleniumwire_options=options)

driver.get('https://2ip.ru/')
```

В итоге получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Taras/PycharmProjects/BooksParser2/test.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver.get('https://2ip.ru/')
  File "C:\Users\Taras\PycharmProjects\BooksParser2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 449, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
  File "C:\Users\Taras\PycharmProjects\BooksParser2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Taras\PycharmProjects\BooksParser2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

Помогите разобраться, что не так ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450158/how-do-i-set-proxy-for-chrome-in-python-webdriver

Comment: Все перепробовал, ничего из этого у меня не работает ((